# How to bookmark every 5th row in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I need to extract every 6th row from a text document. I think the first step is to bookmark them. I'm looking for a regex expression that will do that.

thanks

Comment: Every 5th or 6th row? Starting at row 1 or 5/6?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to extract them, you can search for `([^\n]*\n?){5}` (Starts with line one and selects every fifth).

Search with *Find All in Current Document* -> right click on the parent item of your current search in *search results* window -> *Copy Selected Line(s)*.

Answer (score 0):

To bookmark every 5th row in Notepad ++, go to `Search` > `Replace` menu (shortcut <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>) and do the following:

1. Find what:

   ```
    ([^\n]*\n?){5}
   ```
2. Select radio button "Regular Expression"
3. Then press `Enter`

Answer (score 0):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?:^.+\R){5}(^.+\R)`
- Replace with: `$1`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(?:         # non capture group
  ^           # beginning of line
    .+          # 1 or more any character but newline
    \R          # any kind of linebreak
){5}        # end group, must appear 5 times
(           # group 1
  ^           # beginning of line
    .+          # 1 or more any character but newline
    \R          # any kind of linebreak
)           # end group
```

**Replacement:**

```
$1      # content of group 1, the 6th line
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]